# How to drop floating point values from dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe but has similar contents to the one below.

```
d = {'col1': [1, -2.654, 3, 1.995]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

Output
   col1  
0     1    
1     -2.654   
2     3    
3     1.995
```

I would like to delete the floating point values so rows 1 and 3 would be deleted.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
d = {'col1': [1, -2.654, 3, 1.995]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df[df.col1 == round(df.col1)]

#    col1
# 0   1.0
# 2   3.0
```

Comment: When I try this I get `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>`, I believe this is because the original dataframe datatype was an object that has int and float types in it

Comment: Hmm. it works for me.Usually, you cannot have `int` and `float` types in the same column. Pandas will always pick the larger datatype (ie convert int to float).
What version are you on?

Comment: I'm using jupyter notebook version 5.7.4 through Anaconda so I think everything is the latest version. But how can that be the case if col1 has the datatype of an object. If it converted the entire column wouldn't the datatype be float64 and not an object. There were strings in col1 but I had already droped those rows.

Comment: ok, I con't know how your dataframe looks like. if you are certain, that you don't have only numeric values in your dataframe, you can cast the column to float first, then apply the filter: `df = df.astype({'col1': 'float'})`

Comment: You also may want to consider to sanitize your data before creating your dataframe.

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong, thanks for the help!